# Connecting Laravel from vagrant to host MSSQL express

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, sql-server-express

I have Laravel on a vagrant box trying to connect to the hosts MSSQL. For the life of me cannot seem to establish a connection.

How do I determine the host's IP for MSSQL?

Comment: Run `netstat -rn` from within Vagrant. This will give you a list of IP's. For `0.0.0.0`, use the `Gateway` address. Which will most likely be `192.168.1.1`

Comment: if you have a bridge connection your guest can reach your host using the host IP - make sure you start MSSQL on `0.0.0.0` and not only localhost

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it was a different IP but your solution worked for me. Post as answer to get credit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host machine can be accessed through the "Guest Additions" package. You can identify the IP of the Host by running `netstat -rn`.

Through the list, find what is most likely `0.0.0.0` and use the associated `Gateway` IP which is probably `192.168.1.1.`